# Discord Bot: How to check if the client message is the correct answer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to build a simple math game and it works fine, but I can't check if the answer someone gives to the math problem is correct or not.

I made an if statement to see if the answer matches the message content:

```js
if (msg.content == answer) {
  msg.reply('correct');
}
```

The problem is that `msg.content` only accepts a string, not an integer. Can anyone help me fix that issue?

Here is the full code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  var minimum = 1;
  var maximum = 100;
  var int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
  var int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
  if (msg.author.bot) return;
  //step 1
  if (msg.content === 'mathplus') {
    msg.reply(`hi what is ${int1} + ${int2}`);
    var answer = int1 + int2;

    console.log(answer);
  }

  //check if answer is correct -- where the problem is
  if (msg.content == answer) {
    msg.reply('correct');
  }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: Please provide more of your code.

Comment: Use the function [`isNan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if its **N**ot **a** **N**umber. Returns true if its not. Also for question and answer type, I think you might need [MessageCollector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages).

Comment: @Daweed here is my code https://replit.com/@YaraMoharrm/discord-bot#index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is NOT that the `msg.content` is not an integer. You're correctly using double equals here (and `5 == '5'`). The problem is that `answer` is no longer the sum of `int1` and `int2`, it's `undefined`. When you use the `mathplus` command, you define the `answer` but if you send a new message with the answer, it's no longer available.

Check out the example below:

```js
function test(command) {
  if (command === 'mathplus') {
    var answer = 5
    console.log(`"mathplus" command. The answer is ${answer}`)
  }

  if (command == answer) {
    console.log('correct')
  }

  console.log({
    answer,
    command
  })
}

test('mathplus')
test('5')
```

As Radnerus mentioned in their comment, you can use [message collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors) to wait for an answer from the user. I've added an example below how you could use it with lots of comments:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '!';

// helper function to get a number between min and max
function randomInt(min, max) {
  if (min > max) [min, max] = [max, min];

  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'mathplus') {
    const int1 = randomInt(0, 100);
    const int2 = randomInt(0, 100);
    const answer = int1 + int2;

    // we only wait for 30s for an answer
    const maxWait = 30000; // in ms
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#f8cf4d')
      .setTitle(`Hey ${message.author.username}! What is ${int1} + ${int2}? `);

    await message.channel.send(embed);

    // filter checks if the response is from the same author who typed the command
    const filter = (response) => response.author.id === message.author.id;

    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
      // set up the max wait time the collector runs
      time: maxWait,
    });

    // fires when a response is collected
    collector.on('collect', (response) => {
      if (parseInt(response.content, 10) === answer) {
        message.channel.send(
          ` Woohoo, ${response.author}! \n\nYou're a maths genius, the correct answer was \`${answer}\`.`,
        );
        // the answer is correct, so stop this collector and emit the "end" event
        collector.stop();
      } else {
        // give the user another chance if the response is incorrect
        message.channel.send(
          `Oh, ${response.author}, \`${response.content}\` is not correct... \nDo you want to try again?`,
        );
      }
    });

    // fires when the collector is finished collecting
    collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
      // only send a message when the "end" event fires because of timeout
      if (reason !== 'time') return;

      // if there are incorrect answers
      if (collected.size > 0) {
        return message.channel.send(
          `Ah, ${message.author}. Out of ${collected.size} guess${
            collected.size > 1 ? 'es' : ''
          } you couldn't find the number \`${answer}\`. I'm not saying you're slow, but no more answers are accepted.`,
        );
      }

      // if the user haven't submitted any answer, let's get a bit more aggressive
      return message.channel.send(
        `Okay, ${message.author}, I'm bored and I can't wait any longer. No more answers are accepted. At least you could have tried...`,
      );
    });
  }
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try this approach

```js
if(!parseInt(message.content)){ // If the message wasn't actually a number
    return message.reply("You can only answer numbers");
}
if(parseInt(message.content) === answer){ // Correct answer
    return message.reply("Correct answer");
}else{ // Wrong answer
    return message.reply("Oops");
}
```

`parseInt()` converts string to integers. So `parseInt("10.103")` would return `10`. If you need to work with floating numbers try `parseFloat()`
Use these resources to learn more about these functions
**Resources**

- [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)